# Printer Drivers for old models of Samsung, Xerox or Dell printers ( like Samsung ML-1520)

Tags: printing, driver

I've got a quite old Samsung printer, model ML-1520. I can not find any drivers for it. Samsung seems to have stopped supporting OS X, and Apple only [offers drivers for models](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL905?locale=en_GB) not older than ML-1630.

I've tried to install the drivers by Apple and setup my printer as 1630 and other models, but it doesn't print.

Where can I find proper drivers?

<sub>(I'm writing both Q&A. For the purpose of search optimization I've added extra vendors in the header. My solution is applicable to all those vendors).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to do: check if your printer is [supported by Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL905?locale=en_GB). It was not true in my case, but may be true in yours.

There are at least two opensource driver packages, supporting the printers which are abandoned by their vendors:

## [SpliX](http://guigo.us/mac/splix/).

> a set of [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/) Printer drivers for SPL (Samsung Printer Language) printers. If you have a such printer, you need to download and use SpliX.

**Supported Printers**

- Dell 1100, 1110
- Samsung CLP-200, CLP-300, CLP-500, CLP-600, CLP-610, CLX-216X, CLX-2170, CLX-3160, ML-1510, ML-1520, ML-1610, ML-1630, ML-1710, ML-1740, ML-1750, ML-2010, ML-2150, ML-2250, ML-2510, ML-2550, ML-2571, ML-3050, ML-3560
- Xerox Phaser 3115, 3116, 3117, 3120, 3121, 3122, 3130, 3150, 3420, 3425, 5500, 6100, 6110

## [Samsung-GDI for Mac OS X](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/macosx/samsung-gdi#Printers)

**Supported Printers**

- Generic GDI Printer
- Lexmark
- Samsung ML-200, ML-210, ML-1000, ML-1010, ML-1020, ML-1200, ML-1210, ML-1220, ML-1410, ML-1430, ML-1440, ML-1510, ML-1520, ML-1610, ML-1710, ML-1740, ML-1750, ML-2010, ML-2150, ML-2250, ML-2550, ML-4500, ML-5080, ML-6040

## Personal experience

I first installed SpliX and it worked well with documents printed from MS Word or PDFs. But it failed with printing `.jpg` images from Preview app or command-line `lpr` utility. So I switched to Samsung-GDI, which handles `.jpg` well.

Also, if a printer is set up twice with different drivers it doesn't work with any of them. So you should only have one printer in `Settings` > `Printers` (per each device). You can have both driver packs installed on your system, though.

Similar problem was discussed in [Xerox 3117 driver for OS X Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154197/xerox-3117-driver-for-os-x-yosemite)

Answer (score 2):

For Samsung Printer Drivers on 10.14.x Mojave, this worked!

- Download http://splix.ap2c.org/ and unzip to get PPDs

  - Select the PPD for your printer, mine was Samsung ML-1740 `ml1740pt.ppd`
- Download http://guigo.us/mac/splix/ Download and install SpliX 2.0.0

  - It will fail, that's OK, it still installs the prerequisities
  - Go to System Preferences > Printers > Install Printer > Select USB Printer > Select Other Driver > Select the PPD file.

References:

- https://dawning.ca/2017/ml1610-blaster-drivers-for-samsung-ml1610-on-macos-high-sierra/
- https://github.com/docdawning/ml1610-blaster
- Another list of PPDs https://github.com/CvH/splix/tree/master/ppd

Comment: Some/most of the methods in this answer don't work anymore, upvoted for giving me a direction, and posted a new answer with what works now.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal answer is the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, on MacOS sonoma (14.0), I made it work for my ML-1610 using [Install an old Samsung Printer on Catalina / Big Sur macOS using outdated Splix 2.0.0](https://github.com/peekpt/Old-Samsung-Printer-Splix-Catalina).

Comment: Please try to include essential parts of the answer here, instead of just providing a link. This is to (a) avoid users from going off-site and (b) to ensure we have the answer on here if the link goes broken.

Comment: Link-only answer, which is prone to [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Well, you actually need the files from this github repo, there is nothing i can mention here which will work without those files on the provided gihtub repo link.